# Prometheus alert when pod is in Pending for more than 2 minutes

Tags: prometheus, promql

We have a system that launches short-lived pods in the Kubernetes cluster and waits up to 2 minutes when they start running, otherwise, it kills them.
I would like to have alerts when this happens using Prometheus.

I created the following alert expression:
`min_over_time(sum by (namespace, pod) (kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Pending"})[2m:30s]) > 0`
and faced with many false positive notifications.

[image: an example of a pod transition between Pending and Running phases]

As far as I understand, when Prometheus evaluates the expression in the early stage of the pod life cycle it will always return 1 and I need to add an additional condition to say Prometheus something like "If the pod is in Pending state for 2 mins and there are more then 4 datapoints return 1".
Does somebody know how to extend the expression above and add to it that additional condition?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried having an alerting rule with `for: 2m`:

```
  - alert: PodIsInPendingState
    expr: kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Pending"} > 0
    for: 2m
```

This would fire if there are some pods in Pending state for more than 2m.